# How to prove that the convergent value of a sequence is unique?

Tags: real-analysis

I need a little support in the following proposition:

Let $(x_n)$ be a convergene sequence in $\mathbb{R}$ and $x_n \rightarrow a $ and $x_n \rightarrow b $ , then $a=b$

My proof is:

Consider $|a-b| = |a-x_n + x_n-b| \le |a-x_n| + |x_n-b| < \frac{\epsilon}{2} + \frac{\epsilon}{2} = \epsilon$ 
so it follows tat $|a-b| <\epsilon$ then $a = b$

is that correct?

Comment: The idea is correct but the proof is incomplete.

Comment: what is missing?

Comment: You haven't ever defined a symbol. You didn't make any assumptions about $\epsilon$, you haven't connected it with the sequence $\{x_n\}$, you haven't stated that $|a - b| < \epsilon$ holds for *all* positive $\epsilon$... Essentially all of the explanation of the proof is missing here.

Comment: I see. But if I add those details it will be ok, right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The idea behind your proof is correct but it lacks a certain formality. Namely, you have not specified the value of $n$ you are using when discussing $x_n$! Below, we make the proof formal.

Let $\epsilon > 0$ be given, our goal is to show that $|a-b| < \epsilon$. Since $x_n \to a$, there exists $N_1 \geq 1$ such that
$$
|x_n- a| < \frac{\epsilon}{2}
$$
for all $n \geq N_1$. Similarly, because $x_n \to b$, there is $N_2 \in \mathbb{N}$ with the property that
$$|x_n - b| <\frac{\epsilon}{2}
$$
for all $n \geq N_2$. Now, if $N := \max(N_1,N_2)$ and $n \geq N$, we have by the triangle inequality that
\begin{align*}
|a-b| \leq |a-x_n| + |x_n - b| < \frac{\epsilon}{2} + \frac{\epsilon}{2} = \epsilon.
\end{align*}
Hence, $|a-b| < \epsilon$. Using that $\epsilon >0$ was arbitrary, it follows that $a=b$.